# TextView's gravity not work when has a 9.png background

Tags: android, textview

code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="H" />
```

`@drawable/background` is a 9.png image.
If change to a common png image, gravity works.

How can i fix this? I want to make text in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a drawable (drwable_example.xml) which loads the 9.png file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/background" >
        </bitmap>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

then you can load this as background:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_example"

         >
```

It worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not fixed yet. But change to below code:

`@drawable/background` is a 9.png image.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```